# Is there a best way to find the index value in a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript

Example:-

```
1234 
2456 
5678
```

I need to find the index of the value `7`
Expected output:-

```
[3,3]    // 3rd row and 3rd column.
```

**Note:- Need to consider Time Complexity (ex:-Big(O) notation)**

I am not looking for the below like answers
Sample 1

```js
function findInArr(arr, elm) {
  var occ = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
      if (arr[i][j] == elm)
        occ.push(i+","+j);
  return occ;
}
```

Test:

```js
var numbers = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,2,3,5,5],[9,8,3,4,9]];
var x = findInArr(numbers, 4);
console.log("found " + x.length + " occurences: " + x);
```

**Here time complexity is 'n' rows * 'n' columns**

Sample 2

```js
var numbers=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,2,3,5,5],[9,8,3,4,9]];
var searchItem=2;
numbers.forEach(function(parentItem,parentIndex){
  parentItem.forEach(function(childItem,childIndex){
    if(childItem===searchItem){
      console.log(parentIndex);
      console.log(childIndex);            
    }     
  })
});
```

Comment: Your first version is fine. In an NxM data structure, finding an element in it will take NxM time, worst-case, regardless

Comment: in the first case the correct answer is `[2,2]` not `[3,3]`  first arrays values start at index value= 0

Comment: you can use map, also index starts at 0, so your sample above would be [2,2] not [3,3].

Comment: I don't see how your samples compare. The two codes do totally different things.

Comment: Searching a two-dimensional array always has `O(n²)` time complexity (or more precisely `O(#r * #c)`), there's nothing to be optimised there.

Comment: Maybe your question is more suitable for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

this way ?

```js
const numbers = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,2,3,5,5],[9,8,3,4,9]];

function findInArr(arr, elm) {
  let i = arr.findIndex(x=>x.includes(elm))
  return (i<0) ? [null,null] : [i,arr[i].indexOf(elm)] 
}

console.log( findInArr(numbers, 7))
console.log( findInArr(numbers, 8))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use map, also index starts at 0, so your sample above would be [2,2] not [3,3], Below code, will find all indexes for the search item.

```js
var numbers = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 2, 3, 5, 5],
  [9, 8, 3, 4, 9]
];
var searchItem = 2;
console.log(numbers.map((v, i) => {
  var res = v.filter(f => f === searchItem);
  if (res.length) {
  var ind=v.indexOf(searchItem);
    return [i, ind]
  }


}).filter(f => f !== undefined));
```